# Why "this" keyword stored is different variable and than use to other method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function multiUpload(url, uploder, submit) {
    this.url = url;
    this.browser = uploder;
    this.submit = $(submit);
    self = this;
    multiUpload.prototype.countFile = function (browser) {
        alert(browser);
    }
    this.submit.on("click", this.countFile);
}
```

The above code not work that defined "browser" undefined
than i use

```
multiUpload.prototype.countFile = function(browser){
    alert(this.browser);
}
```

it's alert "Object object"
and when i passed a "this" keyword to "self" vairable

```
self = this;
multiUpload.prototype.countFile = function(browser){
    alert(self.browser);
}
```

now it's work...can any one explain why this happen ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `this` is different inside and outside the function call. Inside the call it is equal to whatever object called the function whereas outside the method it is equal to the window object.

Comment: first of all thanx for given reply.like a other language class object properties pass to method from argument ....but when i am trying in javascript it show me object rather than value....can you explain

Comment: It is because of scope - see the duplicate question for a detailed response.